# Determine length of input a faster computer can run

Tags: algorithm, runtime

This is a homework assignment so I am not looking for the answer, I am just looking for how to find the answer.  I know the answer isn't as simple as 500x100.  Please help as I have no idea what ways to solve this.

"Let A be an algorithm that decides a language L in O(n2) time. There
are two computers, one of them is 100 times faster than the other. On each of the computers, we run A on input x for a fixed amount of time, say, for one second. When A is executed on the slower computer, A decides L for all inputs of length at most 500 and A fails for longer inputs. When A is executed on the faster computer, what is the maximum length of input x such that A can still determine whether x 2 L?"

Comment: Although you cannot accurately determine the answer given only Big-O complexity, you can get a fair comparitive idea by making time equal to t1 = k1 * n^2 and t2 = 100*k1 * n^2